# Remove img src tags and leave base64 data (screenshot from text editor)

Tags: php, image, base64

I'm currently inserting screenshots (through a text editor) into a database and as such the string that is inserted into the db is as follows:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, [BASE64 STRING]" alt="">
```

I'm trying to strip the `<img src=" and " "alt="">` so that I am just left with the `data:image/png;base64, [BASE64 STRING]` so that I can manipulate how the image will be displayed on the other end.

Unfortunately the images have to be inserted as a screenshot through the textarea, and so uploading images/saving them to a different location and storing the location isn't an option.

Is it possible to perhaps strip everything but the base64 data prior to the db insertion, or when retrieving the image if not?

So far I have been playing with preg_replace and strip_tags similar to below but with no avail.

```
echo preg_replace('/<(\s*)img[^<>]*>/i', '', $screenshot);
echo strip_tags($screenshot, '<img>');
```

etc

where $screenshot is the query to fetch the entire string from the db.

Ultimately I want to be able to display the image in a popup or similar, and for that I need the raw base64 image makeup however when inserting a screenshot into a textarea (with a text editor) the tags are already included and so get passed to the db.

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), this regex will grab the src.

```
$img = '<img src="data:data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" alt="">';
preg_match('/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i', $img, $matches);
var_dump($matches);

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(325) "<img src="data:data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7"
  [1]=>
  string(315) "data:data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7"
}
```

Comment: Seems to be returning array(0) { } when I try with the images from my database. They follow a similar structure as the example you have given so not sure why this might be.

Comment: What are a few of the image strings from your database?

Comment: I've just experimented with some different screenshots, it seems if I screenshot with full screen (F11) and insert that data, your preg_match works, but if I screenshot out of full screen with task / control bars etc and insert that screenshot it returns the array 0 as above. A very odd bug, I wonder what might be causing that?